# Mailgun: Is there a way to retrieve a stored message a webhook call gave up on?

Tags: mailgun

I have a Mailgun application with an incoming route set up in the following way:

```
match_recipient('me@example.com')
store(notify='https://www.example.com/endpoint')
```

At some point, I switched the domain from `www.example.com` to `www.example2.com` with a 301 redirect through the DNS provider (read: I cannot access the logs..) without changing the Mailgun routes.

Over the course of a few days I got a bunch of permanent errors in the logs, since the webhook does not seem to follow redirects.

Now, I'd like to try to retrieve these stored messages, but there I don't find a way to get to the original ID.

Here is what is stored in the Mailgun event log:

```
{
  "severity": "permanent",
  "tags": [],
  "delivery-status": {
    "retry-seconds": 14400,
    "message": "<html><body>You are being <a href=\"https://www.example2.com/endpoint\">redirected</a>.</body></html>",
    "code": 301,
    "description": "<html><body>You are being <a href=\"https://www.example2.com/endpoint\">redirected</a>.</body></html>",
    "session-seconds": 0.7563347816467285
  },
  "envelope": {
    "targets": "https://www.example.com/endpoint",
    "transport": "http",
    "sender": "postmaster@example.com"
  },
  "log-level": "error",
  "id": "dffZ3qigQpyKGNdwhfj26A",
  "campaigns": [],
  "reason": "old",
  "user-variables": {},
  "flags": {
    "is-routed": null,
    "is-authenticated": true,
    "is-callback": true,
    "is-system-test": false,
    "is-test-mode": false
  },
  "timestamp": 1430473028.303534,
  "message": {
    "headers": {
      "to": null,
      "message-id": "20150430214155.10820.14949@example.com",
      "from": "postmaster@example.com",
      "subject": null
    },
    "attachments": [],
    "recipients": [
      "https://example.com/endpoint"
    ],
    "size": 47467
  },
  "recipient": "https://example.com/endpoint",
  "event": "failed"
}
```

(1) In the above the `id` seems to represent the Event ID, which I believe is irrelevant, and the message ID seems to be `20150430214155.10820.14949`.

(2) In a typical webhook success scenario, the message posted to the server contains a callback-URL to retrieve the message that looks like this:

```
https://api.mailgun.net/v2/domains/www.example.com/messages/WyI4MzNheDUxMmRjIiwgWyI0ZWFiNWM1Mi05Zjg4LTRkMjctYjdhMS04ZTM3Y2E3ZDJmNTkiXSwgIm1haWxndW4iLCAib2xkY29rZSJd
```

This is a Base64 encoded message of the following (all UIDs are modified):

```
["833ax512dc", ["4eab5c52-9f88-4d27-b7a1-8e37ca7d2f59"], "mailgun", "oldcoke"]
```

Is there a way to construct the stored-message retrieval URL using the message ID 20150430214155.10820.14949 ?

Answer (score 3):

This is maybe a little too late for [AmitA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/455826/amita)'s need, but if anyone else wants to know a way to get that retrieval URL, my approach was to use the Events API:

GET /events?message-id={your message ID}

This returns a response, with a list of results under an 'items' key. These items will have that URL under the 'storage' key, as 'url'.

So, if `response` is the response from that GET call, the URL for the first response will be found at `response['items'][0]['storage']['url']`.

I hope that helps someone out there!

Comment: some additional snippet
`msg_url = response['items'][0]['storage']['url']
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
requests.get(url=msg_url,auth=HTTPBasicAuth('api','Your_MailGunKey').json()`